# Find if list of coordinates form a loop

Tags: python, list, graph-theory, path-finding

So I have a list of points that generally form a sort of circular shape except there are often little offshoots from the circle that are essentially just lines from say the border of the circle going in a certain direction. I want to create a function that when given this list of coordinates/points finds whether there exists a complete path in this set of points.

I've thought about creating a start point and finding whether there exists a path that doesn't repeat points (ie (1,1) -> (2, 1) -> (1,1) disallowed) and could get back to the start point; however, if the start point is in an offshoot of the circle, this wouldn't work.

For instance, a list of coordinates

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3], [3, 4], [4, 4], [3, 2], [3, 1], [3, 0], [2, -1], [1, -1], [0, -1]]
```

would form a complete path while if I take out `[1, -1]` it would not form a complete path.

Comment: What is the rule for saying that two points are connected? From the example it would seem that the rule should be that no coordinate has an absolute change greater than 1, but in that case, you would still have a path without repeats after removing `[2, 0]` (namely `[[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]]`).

Comment: @fuglede You're absolutely right. Updated example to be more accurate of what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can find a similar problem (for which a solution is provided) at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-simple-closed-path-for-a-given-set-of-points/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [simple cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28graph_theory%29#Definitions). The graph theory package `networkx` provides a method for finding those in [`simple_cycles`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html#networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles). All we need to do is a tiny bit of leg work to set up the graph:

```
import networkx as nx

def has_simple_cycle(l, start):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_edges_from((v1, v2) for v1 in l for v2 in l if v1 != v2 and max(abs(v1[0] - v2[0]), abs(v1[1] - v2[1])) <= 1)
    return any(start in c and len(c) > 2 for c in nx.simple_cycles(G))
```

On your given examples:

```
In [26]: has_simple_cycle(l=[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 4), (3, 2), (3, 1), (3, 0), (2, -1), (1, -1), (0, -1)], start=(0, 0))
Out[26]: True

In [27]: has_simple_cycle(l=[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 4), (3, 2), (3, 1), (3, 0), (2, -1), (0, -1)], start=(0, 0))
Out[27]: False
```